# How to achieve grid layout similar to new IO14 app

Tags: android, android-gridview

I would like to achieve a layout similar to the new IO14 app using gridview/gridlayout, but I am unable to do so using gridview as I get 4 items of equal size. I would like to achieve something like this :
[image]

that is, one rectangular grid item on top of two smaller squares. How can I achieve this ? Could someone please help me out ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [quiltview library from github](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary)